Determine max installable RAM for a CPU that supports but no official motherboard support
I have a Lenovo Ideapad-520IKB laptop with a single 16GB memory SODIMM module and no soldered memory on motherboard. I want to upgrade it to 32GB (or 24GB if 32 not possible)
When I searched Lenovo spec it states that max RAM is 16GB but its CPU (i.e. Intel 8550u) supports up to 32GB. As this motherboard is new and has no northbridge chip, why the spec has lowered the max RAM? If I buy a 32GB DDR4 and replace the current 16GB, do I end up with a working system or not?
PS.1 : The crucial tool also says max is 16GB.
PS.2 : There are some websites that claim selling 32GB ram for my laptop model like this and this. But I don't know if they are reliable.
UPDATE: I bought a 32GB module and tested it. It works perfectly!

My advice. Just buy from a store that allows returns. Try installing it, if it works great!, if not return it.

Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ -- perhaps some user has experience. However, even if it worked on that particular setup, there's no guarantee it would work on yours.

It will probably work.
This often happens when the memory kits with 1x32GB were generally available after the notebook was launched, so they don't bother changing the specs. The notebook is from 2017~2018, and the only SO-DIMM DDR4-2400 1x32GB that I was able to find is the Crucial one, launched in 2019~2020.
Keep in mind that this is untested by the manufacturer, so you CAN have some issues with it. Most of the motherboard X RAM compatibility comes from trial and error. Also, manufacturers can impose some restrictions to avoid the 'custom-competition' between lower-end products.
Lenovo changes a lot of the specs between its notebooks, but it seems that the highest spec for the Ideapad-520IKB is the motherboard NM-B452 (i7-8550u CPU, 4GB RAM soldered and a MX150 2G), which has only one socket for a SO-DIMM DDR4-2400 RAM. This is compatible with 32GB sticks and the memory controller for the SoC is also compatible.

Thank you bro! Actually I went to a store and tested and bought it and it's working
